# How do I generate a contour graph from a function in R?

Tags: r, math, plot, model, simulation

For example, I have a diffusion equation as below, where the object generates substance A:
[image: Concentration of substrate A vs distance from a spherical cell]

This is the equation: C = Q/(4πDr), where C is the concentration, Q is the efflux, D is diffusivity and r is distance from the cell center.
And this is my R code:

```
model <- function(Q,D,r) {Q/(4*pi*D*r)*10^9}
r <- seq(0.5,10,0.1)
C <- model(Q=2.7*10^-18, D=2*10^-9, r=r)
plot(r, C, col="red", type="l")
```

I'd like to translate the function into a contour graph, something like Karp-Boss et al. (1996) illustrated: [image: Concentration distributions of a substance A around cells]

How can I achieve that with R?

Comment: `emdbook::curve3d()` is one way to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have your data, I can provide a small example. You can use your own function to generate your data set passed to `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density))
v + geom_contour()
```

[image]

You can go from there and adapt the code to your problem / add more stuff.